# Are these brake pads good or poor quality?

Tags: brakes, brake-pad

I bought these pads, that were supposed to be premium, ceramic pads, from a premium manufacturer.
After a while, they started to be extremely noisy (squeaking and grinding metal-to-metal noises when the car was driving with the brakes released).

This is what they looked like after approx 500km on the road. Are the huge metal pieces normal? The rotors had grooves after these pads were used.
[image: photo brake pads]

Comment: I'm no expert or mechanic but.. I'm not sure how you drive your car, but as far as I'm aware ceramic pads sqeak _a lot_ under normal driving conditions, because the brakes _don't get hot enough_. I'd suggest trying some brake-quiet on the back of the pad's backing plate. This should absorb the vibrations. As for the grinding noise while driving, check your cars brake-cleaning / warming up functions (either turn them off or turn it lower or higher), or double check if they're mounter correctly.